# get a value from a json file that contains multiple json objects

Tags: python, json, geojson

i am new to python and json I'm trying to get a specific value for each of the objects that are stored. i am trying to print all of the attributes stores under "NAME" and "OBJECTID" . how can i do this? i have been looking at different answers but I'm still confused. (EDIT: most of the objects in the whole file have different names, my objective is to create a list of all of the names.)
here is a small sample of the file i am using. 
thank you for your help!

```
    {"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[552346.2856999999,380222.8998000007]]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":1,"STFID":"55001442500001","NAME":"0001"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[529754.7249999996,409135.9135999996],[529740.0305000003,408420.03810000047]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":2,"STFID":"55001537250001","NAME":"0001","COUSUBFP":"53725"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[508795.9363000002,441655.3672000002],[508813.49899999984,441181.034]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":6278,"STFID":"55141885750001","NAME":"0001","COUSUBFP":"88575"}}
]}
```

Comment: do you mind posting only the json that's relevant or a smaller sample of your json rather than the entire file? it's hard to understand. thanks :)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "the attributes stores under 'NAME'".  The json data does have some keys such as `"NAME":"0001"`, but I don't know how this relates to the question, if at all.

Comment: sorry, i didn't explain myself. this .json file contains a list of precincts (each line contains a precinct) each of the precinct has a "NAME" key and all i want to do is to print 0001, and so on for all of the "names" of each of the objects. i hope that clears things up

Comment: @YangK sorry about that i deleted most of the filed i didn't need i hope that makes things more clear :) thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your json is like

```
json = {"type": "FeatureCollection", 
        "features": [
            {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[552346.2856999999,380222.8998000007]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":1,"STFID":"55001442500001","NAME":"0001"}},
            {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[529754.7249999996,409135.9135999996],[529740.0305000003,408420.03810000047]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":2,"STFID":"55001537250001","NAME":"0001","COUSUBFP":"53725"}},
            {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[508795.9363000002,441655.3672000002],[508813.49899999984,441181.034]]]},"properties":"OBJECTID":6278,"STFID":"55141885750001","NAME":"0001","COUSUBFP":"88575"}}
            ]}
```

You can get a list of tuples with OBJECTID, NAME using a list comprehension like this:

```
oid_name = [(feature['properties']['OBJECTID'], feature['properties']['NAME']) for feature in json['features']]
```

which will evaluate to

```
[(1, '0001'), (2, '0001'), (6278, '0001')]
```

in this example.

If your need is to look up the name for an object, you might find it more useful to use a dictionary for this:

```
names = {feature['properties']['OBJECTID']: feature['properties']['NAME'] for feature in json['features']}
```

This will allow you to look up the name like this:

```
>>> names[1]
'0001'
```